# How can I call a new page and add in the value of a form variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to link to a new page in the format:

```
/topic/create&qty=4
```

Right now I have the value (which is the number 4) stored in an  field in a form. I tried to put everything in the form with a post but then realized this isn't what I want to do. I just need clicking on a button to go to link to a new page and send the input field value. The reason I want just a link is that later on I will have posts from that form and they will be handled completely differently.

Is this possible? All I know is that

```
<form action="/adminTopics" method="post">
```

isn't what I need.

Comment: What do you mean by "but then realized this isn't what I want to do" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not use POST to send data via url, but you can use GET like this: `/topic/create?qty=4`

EDIT: Clarification

Writing `red` in the text field and pressing submit on this form...

```
<form action="/handler.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="color" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

will produce identical results on the server side to clicking this link

```
<a href='/handler.php?color=red'>rum</a>
```

Comment: Oh okay so if I use method="get" then is it the same as a normal page link?

Comment: exactly - posting a form with method get, containing an input having name `color` and value `red` is the same as a link with `?color=red` appended to the end

Answer (score 0):

If the url is 
/topic/create?qty=4

and it has to be posted, then you can use

```
<form action="/topic/create" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="qty" value="4" />
</form>

<a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].submit(); return false">Send</a>
```

or

```
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  document.forms[0].submit();
}
</script>
```

If you do NOT need POST, then just call the URL which is the same as a GET

```
<input id="qty" type="hidden" name="qty" value="4" />

<a href="/topic/create"
 onclick="location=this.href+'?qty='+document.getElementById('qty').value; 
 return false">Go</a>
```